# Woocommerce Parent Product Options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can Woocommerce handle individual product but can be grouped together, they different sku, price, weight etc.? Would need to import them since I have thousands. Can't seem to find the correct plugin and can't figure out how to even manually do this from the backend. The example is below but also can be a dropdown as seen on other websites.

Example:
http://www.petco.com/product/100343/Petco-Classic-1-Door-Dog-Crates.aspx?CoreCat=OnSiteSearch